# Parallel computing: from theory to practice

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I studied how to optimize algorithms for multiprocessor systems. Now I would understand in main lines how these algorithms can be transformed into code.

I know that exist some libraries `MPI` based that helps the developement of software portable to different type of systems, but is right the word "portable" that makes me confused: how the program can be authomatically adapted to an arbitrary number of processors at runtime, since this is an option of `mpirun`? How the software can decide the proper topology (mesh, hypercube, tree, ring, etc)? The programmer can specify the preferred topology through `MPI`?

Comment: If you mention multi-core, it sounds like you are talking about a single multi-core computer rather than a network of compute servers. If you are on a network, you probably want MPI or some cluster type of approach. However, if you are on a single computer with multiple cores, you probably don't want message passing but something like OpenMP, OpenCL (if you have a GPU) or threading.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. So, in everyday PCs, multicore software are generally obtained using different threads, with shared memory and divide and conquer or greedy schedule approach, is it?

Comment: in this context, "portable" means that MPI is available on virtually any system from any vendor, and is source code compatible. that basically means that you can compile any MPI application virtually anywhere.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The other questions remain valid :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell let me know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you start the application with a fixed number of cores. Thus, you cannot automatically adapted to an arbitrary number of processors at runtime.

You can tune your software to the topology of your cluster. This is really advanced and for sure not portable. It only makes sense if you have a fixed cluster and are striving for the last bit of performance.

Best regards, Georg